# Recommended location to set response headers?

Tags: headers

I'm looking to set an `Expires` response header for all page requests. I see the `doctype` in the theme's header.php file, so I'm guessing I could set it right before that line, but I'm wondering if there is a better or more appropriate/recommended place to do this?

```
<?php
/** File: /themes/[theme]/header.php
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package goorin
 */
// Should I set the Expires header here?
header('Expires: ' . gmdate($somedatetime) . ' GMT');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
......
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There's a filter for that](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/):

```
function wpse_203745_wp_headers( $headers ) {
    $headers['Expires'] = gmdate( $somedate ) . ' GMT';
    return $headers;
}

add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'wpse_203745_wp_headers' );
```

Comment: Close to 20k … upvoting.

Comment: Thanks. Is it appropriate to add this code to `/themes/[theme]/header.php`? Sorry I'm a WP noob

Comment: No, `functions.php` ;)